# SQLServer triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Please help me to write a trigger that adds new rows to a table.

I have 3 tables in my database:

1. Regions (id, name); id - primary;
2. Technics (id, name); id - primary;
3. Availability (id, region, technic, count); id - primary, region - foreign on Regions.id, Technik - foreign on technics.id.

I want to add new row in Availability for each Technics row on adding row in Regions.

Somethink like:

```
procedure void OnAddNewRegion(int region)
{
    foreach (Row r in Technic)
    {
        Availability.Rows.Add(new Row(id, region, r.Id, 0));
    }
}
```

But in a SQL trigger.
I want to do the same on adding new Technics row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this (assuming Availability.id is an identity), which will also handle multiple rows being inserted at one time:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Regions ON Regions 
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO Availability 
        (region, technic, count)
    SELECT
        i.id, t.id, 0
        FROM INSERTED            i
            CROSS JOIN Technics  t

GO
```

you don't say how Regions joins with Technics, so I cross joined them (every inserted Regions, gets one row for every Technics).

Comment: I guess the JOIN is via the Availability table, so cross join seems correct

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a cleaner solution for implementing this specific business/insert logic would be to use a Stored Procedure.

Simply create a stored procedure to handle the logic for inserting records to the Region table.

Comment: Why do you feel that? A trigger is really nothing more than a stored procedure that runs automatically under certain conditions. Using a trigger prevents someone forgetting/failing to run the stored procedure, thus enforcing the business rules the procedure is intended to address.

Comment: On the other hand, triggers act as surprise stored procedures. When you call a sproc, you know it might be inserting accessory rows; it's not as clear with a simple insert statement. Of course, if you used a sproc, you would have to take away insert permissions on that table.